# how to dual boot windows UEFI

Tags: boot, usb

my pc config
soc 5600G 16*2 ram gigabyte B550m board Samsung 1TB m.2 wd 2TB m.2
windows 11 on Samsung disk first partition
i try to install Ubuntu 22.04 on wd/samsung disk
USB bootable disk
boot only show and reboot system !!!
i'll try Ubuntu , fedora, kali, deepin, but no use , just boot on splashscreen and reboot
Windows 11 work fine, Windows USB boot work fine ,

try MBR and GPT also
both m.2 disk also try
but no use
what to do
OMG!!!

Comment: Only consider gpt. Check motherboard manual. Most disable SATA port(s) to use M.2 ports. And if drive in SATA port then M.2 disableabled. I only have one M.2 port on somewhat older Gigabyte Intel based board, and can use external NVMe/USB adapter. Just as fast as internal SSD. NVMe not faster thab SATA SSD with USB3, but in future will hae USB-C port that may be faster.

Comment: Check for any firmware updates for your motherboard too.